# How to close a buffer you don't need any more

Tags: emacs

What's the easiest way to close a buffer in emacs? This would be synonymous with closing an actual file, right? It would probably prompt you to save, if necessary.

I found this in the Emacs help:

`s-^        kill-some-buffers`

But I don't know how to invoke that or what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kill-buffer`, which is usually bound to `C-x k`:

> `C-x k` runs the command `kill-buffer`, which is an interactive built-in
>   function in `C source code'.
>
> It is bound to `C-x k`.
>
> `(kill-buffer &optional BUFFER-OR-NAME)`
>
> Kill the buffer specified by `BUFFER-OR-NAME`. The argument may be a
>   buffer or the name of an existing buffer. Argument `nil` or omitted
>   means kill the current buffer.  Return `t` if the buffer is actually
>   killed, `nil` otherwise.
>
> The functions in `kill-buffer-query-functions` are called with the
>   buffer to be killed as the current buffer.  If any of them returns
>   nil, the buffer is not killed.  The hook `kill-buffer-hook` is run
>   before the buffer is actually killed.  The buffer being killed will be
>   current while the hook is running.  Functions called by any of these
>   hooks are supposed to not change the current buffer.
>
> Any processes that have this buffer as the `process-buffer` are killed
>   with `SIGHUP`.  This function calls `replace-buffer-in-windows` for
>   cleaning up all windows currently displaying the buffer to be killed.

Comment: useful, thanks. do you know what keystroke is meant by `s-^` and other strokes that start with `s-` ? Because it is not actually the s key.

Comment: `s` stands for “super”. On some keyboards, the `alt` key functions as a `super` key. If you don't have a super key, you can type `C-x @ s` as a prefix instead. So you would type `C-x @ s ^`. (Not too often, I would hope.)